# Set up a cronjob every once monday at 7am

Tags: php

Can anyone shed some light?

How to run a code once every Monday at 7am?

Is it like this?

```
* 7 * * 1
```

Comment: That would be every minute between 7 and 8.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**This is how to setup a cronjob:**

```
 # * * * * *  command to execute
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 # │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

In your case, it will be

```
0 7 * * 1 command to execute
```

**What does Asterisk (*) mean**

The asterisk indicates that the cron expression matches for all values of the field. E.g., using an asterisk in the 4th field (month) indicates every month.

---

**Sidenote**

Other special characters in cronjobs

Slash ( / )

Slashes describe increments of ranges. For example 3-59/15 in the 1st field (minutes) indicate the third minute of the hour and every 15 minutes thereafter. The form "*/..." is equivalent to the form "first-last/...", that is, an increment over the largest possible range of the field.

Comma ( , )

Commas are used to separate items of a list. For example, using "MON,WED,FRI" in the 5th field (day of week) means Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays.

Hyphen ( - )

Hyphens define ranges. For example, 2000-2010 indicates every year between 2000 and 2010 AD, inclusive.

Percent ( % )

Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), are changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % are sent to the command as standard input.

See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Thanks Michael, should it be 0 7 * * 1 or 00 7 * * 1

Answer (score 4):

00 7 * * 1

I used [cron-expression-helper](http://www.abunchofutils.com/utils/developer/cron-expression-helper/)